# include file error?

Tags: visual-c++

I have these lines inside my code. I have also included the file in my header list inside my project. But when compile I got the below error. What is my mistake?

```
#ifndef WIN32
#  include <netinet/in.h>
#  include <arpa/inet.h>
#  include <unistd.h>
#  include <netdb.h>
#  include <sys/socket.h>
#  include <sys/un.h>
#  include <pwd.h>
#  include <grp.h>
#else
#  include "getopt.h"
#  include <stdarg.h>
#  pragma comment (lib, "wpcap.lib")
#endif /* ^WIN32 */
```

Error   1   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'getopt.h': No such file or directory  c:\filetry.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getopt is not a visual c header. This might help: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-393293.html

Comment: but the file is already inside my solution's directory. why does ms visual studio could find it?

Comment: Then you need to either add the header to same same directory as the source file that is including it, or add the solution directory that contains the header to the project's include path.